# Describing all the irreducible and f.g. completely reducible modules over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I couldn't even find all the irreducible modules over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ yet.

I know that modules over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is the same as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $V$ equipped with two commuting operators $A, B \in End(V), \; [A,B]=0$.

I also can prove that any $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-module $V$ contains finite dimensional $x$-stable subspace as well as $y$-stable subspace. It makes me think that all the irreducible $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-modules are at least finite dimensional. Am I right? How do I find them?

The second part (finding all the completely reducible modules) I didn't actually try to solve yet because I obviously need to understand the first part to do that. It would be nice to have a hint for that.

Comment: Do you remember any theorems about commuting matrices from linear algebra?

Comment: If they are diagonalizable then they are simultaneously diagonalizable. But what if they aren’t?

Comment: Do you know the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, yes

Answer (score 1):

Okay well a more general version of the "two commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable" theorem is the theorem that any two commuting square matrices are simultaneously upper-triangularizable.  It is essentially equivalent to the statement you are trying to prove though. Here is a sketch of how to prove it:

Suppose we have a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space with two commuting linear maps $X$ and $Y$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, there exists an eigenvector for $X$ with some eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ commute, $Y$ acts on the $\lambda$ eigenspace for $X$, so inside there we can again find an eigenvector but this time for $Y$.

Hence we have found a common eigenvector for $X$ and $Y$, if we quotient by this the subspace spanned by this we can repeat this process inductively and obtain the desired upper triangular form.

Comment: Reducing to the finite-dimensional case is nontrivial, though.